# Spring ws authentication interceptor using java config

Tags: java, authentication, interceptor, spring-ws, spring-java-config

I am new to Spring, I have created one SOAP web service using Spring WS, now I want to add basic authentication to it, using interceptor. I am using Java for configuration, no XML. Can someone guide me on how to register a interceptor using Java config and how to do basic authentication.